# How can I execute a series of commands using the Net::SSH::Any module?

Tags: perl

I want to execute multiple commands in the same session after connecting to a server with Net::SSH::Any.

My sample code is as follows:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Net::SSH::Any;

my $host = "ip address";
my $user = "user";
my $passwd = "pass";
my $cmd1 = 'cd /usr/script';

my $ssh = Net::SSH::Any->new($host, user => $user, password => $passwd);
$ssh->system($cmd1);
my $pwd = $ssh->capture("pwd");
print $pwd;
```

I expected the following output:

```
/usr/script
```

but instead I am getting:

```
/home/user
```

How can I execute multiple commands in a single session?

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to chain your commands in the remote shell like this:

```
my $cwd = $ssh->capture( q{cd /usr/script && pwd} );
```

---

You have to do it this way because even though both currently-supported backends to Net::SSH::Any provide other ways to do this (Net::OpenSSH has [`open2pty`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH#pty-pid-ssh-open2pty-opts-cmd) and Net::SSH2 has [channels](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH2::Channel)), the Net::SSH::Any API doesn't expose these.

For example, `system` invokes either Net::OpenSSH's `system` method or creates a Net::SSH2::Channel and invokes `process('exec' => $cmd)` (limited to one command per channel).

Comment: The [development version](https://github.com/salva/p5-Net-SSH-Any) from GitHub already supports that via the `pipe` method. It should be considered an experimental feature yet though. Another option is to use the `stdin_data` option when calling `capture` or any other method. For instance: `$ssh->capture({stdin_data => join("\n", @cmds, "")})`